# Rounding of a Value in Python

Tags: python

Can Python disable or not used the rounding off a float?

This is my sample

```
value = 6.30 * 75.73
```

value:

```
477.099
```

I want only to get the value 477.09 without rounding it off.

Comment: Getting `477.09` from `477.099` **is** rounding off by definition (in a weird way; the actual rounded off value is `477.10`). Do you mean that you want to **print** the value with only two digits after the dot?

Comment: I think you need to explain a bit more what you want in general: if you want `477.09` then use `477.09`. What is your 'rounding' rule for other numbers?

Comment: You can convert it to a string and chop off the last character

Comment: what you want is truncating, which is notoriously difficult with floats...

Comment: Please clarify your needs. Have a look at [decimals](https://pymotw.com/2/decimal/)

Comment: why do you need to truncate like that? I suspect you are trying to solve the wrong problem

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to a string and using string split, append just the last 2 digits of the number

```
num = 477.097
strnum = str(int(num)) + str(num).split(".")[1][:2]
```

Comment: this is the best answer imho ... (as gross as it may be ... )

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called truncating, which is notoriously difficult with float values because of the way they are stored.

If you are doing this for the value itself, you can do this;

```
value = 6.30 * 75.73
value = (( value * 100 ) // 1) * .01

print(value)
```

This will print

> 477.09000000000003

which is equivalent to 477.09 for math calculations.

If you are doing this to display the value, then you can convert to a string and just cut off the last digit that you have. Or, if you don't know how many digits there are after the decimal point, you can get the index of the ".", and cut everything that is 2 after that point, as so:

```
value = 6.30 * 75.73
val_str = str(value)
rounded_str = val_str[:val_str.index('.') + 3]
```

This will print

> 477.09

Comment: That's an interesting thing you did there `// 1`. Can you explain what that is supposed to do?

Comment: its basically guaranteed to do floor division and return an int ... `int(val*100)` would have done effectively the same thing

Comment: Good to know. I've always thought that `//` is only used for integer division

Comment: @JoranBeasley: `//` doesn't return an `int` if the first operand is a float. And `int()` doesn't floor, it rounds. Compare `int(-1.1)` which results in `-1` to `-1.1//1` which gives you `-2.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this? (takes about 100 nanoseconds independent of number of digits)

** note, this does not work for negative numbers as written, so it's of limited use.

```
value = 6.30 * 75.73
print value
print value - value % 0.01

477.097
477.09
```

does it really truncate?

```
value = 1./3.
print value - 0.33333333  # see the leftovers
3.333333331578814e-09

print value - value % 0.01
0.33

print (value - value % 0.01) - 0.33  # no leftovers
0.0

(value - value % 0.01) == 0.33
True
```

Answer (score 0):

convert value to string(if value an integer then the code will still work, because before the conversion to a string we convert to a float):

```
value = = 6.30 * 75.73
value_str = str(float(value))

'{:.2f}'.format(float(value_str[:value_str.index('.') + 3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this hack with [`round`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round):

```
>>> 6.30 * 75.73
>>> 477.099

>>> DIGITS = 2

>>> round(6.30 * 75.73 - 5.0 * 10**(-DIGITS-1), DIGITS)
>>> 477.09
```